# Error trying to replace spaces with underscores

Tags: python

I am trying to ask the player to write a sentence. If the sentence has no spaces, it will return as so. Otherwise, i want all the spaces to be replaced with underscores.

```
sentence = input("Enter de sentence: ")
def replace():
    if sentence.count(" ")>0:
        sentence[1 : sentence.index(" ")] +"_"+ sentence[sentence.index(" ")+1 : len(sentence)]
    else:
        return replace()
        print(replace)
print(replace)
```

no matter what i enter after "Enter de sentence:" is asked, i get this returned:

<function replace at 0x7fecbc2b2280>

I have tried looking up some of the refences for some of the code and tried to change some of the variables, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding many thing it seems, the method name, the variables, ...

Let's go back to a simple one

```
def replace(content):
    if content.count(" ") > 0:
        content = content.replace(" ", "_")
    return content

sentence = input("Enter de sentence: ")
print(replace(sentence))
```

But that example is too much verbose, only to explain you how it works, in fact, you don't need to check if there is spaces or not, just use `str.replace`

```
def no_space(content):
    return content.replace(" ", "_")

sentence = input("Enter de sentence: ")
print(no_space(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

it's just to mention, that the required task can also be done like this:

we separate the input text by using `.split()` method. this creates a list of individual words.
finally we need to re-combine the elements of the list to the final string by using `'_'.join()` with an underscore as an argument.

this can be done as a function or directly in the code.

```
sentence = input().split()
print('_'.join(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` is already a built-in method for string operation.
It will be simle as:

```
sentence = input("Enter de sentence: ").replace(' ','_')
print(sentence)

# Enter de sentence: I want to go to school
# I_want_to_go_to_school
```

But if you want to create custom replace function, your function should receive parameter to pass input strings as argument. In function, initialize a new empty string to store the result, then use for loop to iterate each string in sentence. If string is spaces assign it to underscore and concat to a new string. Lastly return the new string.

```
sentence = input("Enter de sentence: ")
def replaces(sentence):
    new = str()
    for i in sentence:
        if i == ' ':
            i = '_'
            new += i
        else:
            new += i
    return new

print(replaces(sentence))

# Enter de sentence: I want to go to school
# I_want_to_go_to_school
```